# Perl HTML file upload issue. File has zero size

Tags: html, perl, upload, size, zero

I have a perl CGI script, that works, to upload a file from a PC to a Linux server.

It works exactly as intended when I write the call to the CGI in my own HTML form and then execute, but when I put the same call into an existing application, the file is created on the server, but does not get the data, it is size zero.

I have compared environment variables (those I can extract from `%ENV`) and nothing there looks like a cause. I actually tried changing several of the ENV in my own HTML script, to the values the existing application was using, and this did not reveal the problem.

Nothing in the log gives me a clue, the upload operation thinks it was successful.
The user is the same for both tests.  If permissions were an issue, then the file would not even be created on the server.

Results are the same in IE as in Chrome (works from my own HTML script, not from within the application).

What specific set up should I be looking at, to compare?

This is the upload code:

```
if (open(UPLOADFILE, ">$upload_dir/$fname")) {
    binmode UPLOADFILE;

    while (<$from_fh>) {
        print UPLOADFILE;
    }
    close UPLOADFILE;
    $out_msg = "Done with Upload: upload_dir=$upload_dir fname=$fname";
}
else {
    $out_msg = "ERROR opening for upload: upload_dir=$upload_dir filename=$filename";
}
```

I did verify that

- It does NOT enter the while loop, when running from inside the application.
- It does enter the while loop, when called from my own HTML script.

The value of `$from_fh` is the same for both runs.
All values, used in the below block, are exactly the same for both runs.

Comment: Where are you getting `$from_fh` from? It worries me that you say its value is the same in both circumstances as it *should* be different, and will be something like `GLOB(0x90c06c)`

Comment: So you are running a web browser on a Windows PC and you want to upload a file on that PC to Linux system which is running a web server?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the error result of your open?

```
my $err;
open(my $uploadfile, ">", "$upload_dir/$fname") or $err = $!;
if (!$uploadfile) {
  my $out_msg = "ERROR opening for upload: upload_dir=$upload_dir filename=$filename: $err";
}
else {
  ### Stuff
  ...;
}
```

Comment: While having code to check the value of that open command is a good idea, that open command is succeeding.  That is to open the file it is writing to, which it successfully creates.

Comment: He already does that. The `open` is the condition for an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, based on the fact you are embedding it in another application, is that all the input has been read already by some functionality that is part of the other application. For example, if I tried to use this program as part of a CGI script, and I had used the param() function from CGI.pm, then the entire file upload would have been read already. So if my own code tried to read the file again, it would receive zero data, because the data would have been ready already.